# lsof shows that .xsession-errors' deleted files chews up all disk space

Tags: disk-usage

I configured a cronjob that truncates the `~/.xsession-errors` file because it was chewing up all disk space.  This keeps the file smaller than 500K.  The disk space is still being filled.

`lsof +L1 | grep deleted` shows many instances of xsession-errors deleted items that will fill all disk space.  Only a reboot seems to clear this.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice.  I found what was writing to the .xsession-errors file.  kpatient ver. 19 has a bug that fills up the disk.  Ver 21 fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have reset the filesystem's idea of the file size, the program that has `~/.xsession-errors` open has no way of knowing this. It's against the Way of Filesystem to actually delete a file (and free the space) while any process has it open. This lets the logging program simply "write the next block", rather than "open the file;position to End. Read partially filled block;Write the data;Close the file" EVERY time a line of information is logged

Read the `man` page for the program, some programs will reset log files on receipt of a `signal`, others have to be killed and restarted.

How are you starting and stopping your X server? It looks you're leaving X processes lying around, with log files open. Look at `ps -ef`.

You can use `fuser` to send signals to reluctant processes.

Read `man fuser pkill kill X ps;man -a signal`